# How can I turn off vim python-mode's mccabe completely check for just one function?

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

Title pretty much says it, but just to be sure:

I'm not looking for a way of turning off the mccabe check for all callables (functions, methods), just for specific callables I've decided have a good reason to be complex (like a merge sort).

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Append `# noqa` to the `def`-line of your function.

Comment: That works.  Does it turn off just the McCabe check, or does it turn off more than that?

Comment: @dstromberg The [documentation](https://github.com/klen/pylama#skip-lines-noqa) is quite terse, but I assume that all tests are skipped for that line. So it is better to fix all other warnings first, and only then add `#noqa`.